# How Can I get the facebook user id in order to get profile picture?

Tags: php, facebook, web

I just want to put a facebook user profile picture in a simple webpage.

I have read a lot about this, and I found the same answer, "Facebook Api 2.2" cannot query users by username:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/username
```

just by user id, but How Can I do this without the api?, I also read that I have to make the user sign into facebook account in order to get the user id, something like that, but it's just a simple webpage.

I was trying to do this in php.

```
//this is just for showing the page

$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/ricardo.citerio');
var_dump($homepage);
```

Here my idea was to get the page and search for this keyword "fb://profile" in the code and catch the first X characters from that point:

```
fb://profile/621673493 


//I can get this by opening the source code of 
https://www.facebook.com/ricardo.citerio
```

but the big issue is that file_get_contents goes to the index page "www.facebook.com" not to "www.facebook.com/username", with any other page works fine but not with facebook.

Comment: I do not believe that you can do this without the API. Why not use the API?

Comment: That's the issue, I just need the user id in order to query anything to the API, but I dont know How To get the id user

Comment: people used to do this: http://graph.facebook.com/ricardo.citerio/picture to get  the profile picture, That's not working anymore

Comment: How do you know the user's username if they've not authenticated with your site?

Comment: Is it mandatory the users authenticated with my site in order to get a simple pic of them?

Comment: It would seem that way. How else would you get a picture of them? By authenticating they give you permission to access certain data. That's the purpose of authentication. My question still stands. How do you get their username if they've not authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't do it without the API. You must authenticate users in order to use their data. Please read Facebook Platform Policies here: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/